# Get 401 attempting to add attachment to envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am using this endpoint

```
PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/attachments
```

to add an attachment to an envelope in Postman.  It gives me a 401 (unauthorized).  However, when I use the SAME account id and envelope id to issue a resend using

```
/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients
```

it works fine.  What do I need to do to correct my problem?

[Screen capture of Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlBZI.png)

[Screen capture of request and response in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHi4s.png)

Comment: "*404 (unauthorized)*" If you believe a 404 error code corresponds to an Unauthorized condition, you may want to review your understanding of HTTP error codes. 404 is used to indicate a resource which could not be found for the URL specified.

Comment: Pardon me.  Typographical error.  It's a 401.  Isn't that "unauthorized"?

Comment: Please use [logging](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus) to capture the exact API request/response sequence and then **update** your question with the API log. (Remove any personal info.)

Comment: Thank you.  It may take me a while to get authorization to do that but I'll start the process immediately.

Comment: I enabled logging, executed my request, waited 5 minutes (just in case), and downloaded the log.  The request did not show up in the log at all.

Comment: The following is a screen capture of the request and response in Postman:

Comment: @Larry K  I have put a screen capture of the request and response above.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is

> The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified.

See this [article](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-from-the-trenches-may-2020#:%7E:text=The%20message%20%22An%20Integrator%20key,to%20parse%20your%20authentication%20header.) for info on the fix. From the article:

> The message "An Integrator key was not specified" typically means DocuSign wasn't able to parse your authentication header. If you're using Legacy Header authentication, confirm your x-DocuSign-Authentication header is present, follows the correct JSON or XML formatting, and has no special characters or trailing spaces.
>
> If this error occurs while you're using an OAuth Authentication workflow, confirm your header has a key of authorization, and the value has a prefix of Bearer before the token.

### The transaction was not in the API logging record

This is because the error occurred during the authentication phase of the request. Since the request could not be authenticated, it could not be associated with your user ID and its logging record.

Comment: Thank you, @Larry K.

1.  The X-DocuSign-Authentication header is present and is in the proper format.
2.  The identical format for the X-DocuSign-Authentication is working in other API requests.

My present hypothesis is that there are SOME API requests that do not support legacy authentication.  If so, I have found no documentation to that effect.  I am attempting to construct an experiment to verify that.

Comment: I suggest that you contact DocuSign developer support.